# Share a video from my android app

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app i am creating a video and storing it in the sdcard. I want to share that video. In any mode as the choice of the user. I tried some sample like this. But i don't know the exact way. Please help me.

```
 share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("video/*");
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("file://"+"/mnt/sdcard/path"));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share via"));
        }
    });
```

But in the chooser it doesn't shows any application. Help me in the right way.

Answer (score 2):

First, use a real MIME type (not a wildcard).

Second, use the actual path to the video that you wish to share (rather than an incorrectly hardcoded path to a directory).

Third, use `setDataAndType()` to set the `Uri` and MIME type in one call, as I believe `setData()` will wipe out the previously-set MIME type.

Comment: what is the MIME type here and what is its impact if we doesn't set.shall i know??

Comment: @kalyanpvs: "what is the MIME type here" -- that depends upon the video you are sharing. "what is its impact if we doesn't set" -- `ACTION_SEND` may not find any valid ways to share the video.

Comment: sir With using intent.setType() method we have already set the type..then shall we need to again set the data and type for the intent..or one is enough??or setType() is different from setDataAndType()??

Comment: @kalyanpvs: If you take the time to read [the documentation for `setData()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setData%28android.net.Uri%29), you will read the following warning: "This method automatically clears any type that was previously set by setType(String)". Hence, I recommend replacing your `setData()` and `setType()` methods will [a *single* call to `setDataAndType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setDataAndType%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that (at least on Android 5.1+) you need to supply Uri with content paths. Here's how to create a content path from a filepath (that I save to the public video directory )

```
public static Uri getVideoContentUri(Context context, String filePath )//File imageFile)
    {
        //String filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID }, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + "=? ",
                new String[] { filePath }, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
            Uri baseUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/videos/media");
            return Uri.withAppendedPath(baseUri, "" + id);
        }
        else
        {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, filePath);
            return context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        }
    }
```